# Matplotlib Figure() (Case Sensitive) Does not have attribute figlegend

Tags: matplotlib, python-2.7, figure

If I initialize my figure in matplotlib by `myfigure=Figure((5.0, 4.0), dpi=100)` why cant I use `figlegend(handles,labels,'upper center')`? Why cant I generally use the functions that work with `myfigure = plt.figure()`? (If i imported like `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`)

If i could how would i do that?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figlegend pyplot function is a really simple wrapper to a figure method. The code for figlegend:

```
def figlegend(handles, labels, loc, **kwargs):
    ...
    l = gcf().legend(handles, labels, loc, **kwargs)
    draw_if_interactive()
    return l
```

As you can see, all you really need to do is use the legend method on a figure to achieve the same results.

HTH

Comment: Awsome pelson! i just used l= used myFigure.legend(handles, labels, loc, **kwargs) and now i have a figlegend! thx a mill pelson for pointing that out!!!!

Comment: Your welcome! The pyplot code isn't magic, and is well worth a read if you ever find something isn't quite working as you are expecting.